# Previous website does not work with paginated content on reputation tab

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, pagination, browsers

I was browsing my reputation history (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2047418/filip-bartuzi?tab=reputation), went to the second page and then clicked "back" button to go to previous URI (i.e.first page).

URL changes from https://stackoverflow.com/users/2047418/filip-bartuzi?tab=reputation&sort=time&StartDate=2017-05-03%2019:28:57Z&page=2 to https://stackoverflow.com/users/2047418/filip-bartuzi?tab=reputation but the content of the second page is shown. Also "active page" indicator (orange color) in CSS is on the second page.

Edit:

I've included video showing this bug http://recordit.co/VOXvRZ893t

Comment: No bug here. The contents are loaded with AJAX, without full page refresh.

Comment: @ShadowWizard A valid FR though, typically this is accomplished by updating and tracking the fragment in the URL. *Debatably* a bug given that it's not done, but meh. It's one of my biggest SE peeves.